# Error 15404 showing when trying to run dtsx file SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

Can anyone help, I have a SQL table built in my database that feeds from an excel file that will be regularly updated. I got it working fine, but I need the data in SSMS to be updated upon refresh (ie: fetch the latest from the excel file).
[image: ScreenshotSSMS]

I have created a dtsx file which I believe is what I need in order to update, but when I go to execute on SSMS I get this error message:

> The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (DESKTOP-DACFOFI\chris) of job UpdateCSKASubs has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DESKTOP-DACFOFI\chris', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).

I saw on other forums that the solution was to change Owner to "sa", but that gave me this error message:

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 15.0.2000.5 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  16:03:36  Error: 2021-04-03 16:03:36.61     Code: 0xC0011007     Source: {122CA6EC-6AEA-452B-95FC-516979E12E61}      Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End Error  Error: 2021-04-03 16:03:36.62     Code: 0xC0011002     Source: {122CA6EC-6AEA-452B-95FC-516979E12E61}

> Description: Failed to open package file "C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\CSKA\ImportFromExcel.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005 "Access is denied.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.  End Error  Could not load package "C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\CSKA\ImportFromExcel.dtsx" because of error 0xC0011002.  Description: Failed to open package file "C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\CSKA\ImportFromExcel.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005 "Access is denied.".  This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document.

> This can be the result of specifying an incorrect file name when
> calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect format.
> Source: {122CA6EC-6AEA-452B-95FC-516979E12E61}  Started:  16:03:36
> Finished: 16:03:36  Elapsed:  0.016 seconds.  The package could not be
> found.  The step failed.

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: Create an empty, do nothing, SSIS package and deploy to the package store (150\dts\packages) and see if you can run it via sa owning the job. This was we can eliminate something specific to your package vs environmental

Answer (score 0):

When you run it as sa, the error message indicates that the SQL Agent process cannot access a package in your user space.

To resolve that, deploy the package to somewhere the sql agent can access. The DTS Package Store is likely as good as any. Your error message indicates "SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 15" so v15 is also SQL Server 2019 so copy the file to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Packages
```

Unless you need to run it in 32 bit mode, then copy to (I *think* - it's been a long while since I've dealt with file system deploys)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Packages
```

Depending on whether the Excel file is a local or network resource, you might then run into an issue with connecting to the UNC/mount path but that'll be an artifact of how you have SQL Server/Agent and the job (credentialed user?) set up.

Comment: Thanks, so tried both and got these errors:

Comment: No joy with those unfortunately. still getting Access Denied type messages.